# Python library for rotation and translation on a seesaw-like object

Tags: python, robotics, kinematics

I'd like to do calculations on the 3D positions on both end's of a rigid object (see spot where the children are usually sitting in image below). The geometrical situation of the rigid object corresponds to a seesaw. Rotation has to be possible on three axes and can be represented by a ball bearing, which initially is located at the middle of the rod.

The input to the desired function should consist of three rotations performed at the position of the ball bearing, three translations along the bearing and the initial 3D positions of both ends of the object.

The output needs to be the calculated new 3D positions of both ends.

Does anyone know a python library that does provide functionalities regarding this issue?

[image: Text]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found out that [Open3D](http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.7.0/python_api/open3d.geometry.PointCloud.html) has implemented exactly what I was looking for. As it is working with point clouds, all that needs to be done is to create two points in 3D space, define a rotation matrix and the center (= ball bearing in this case). The function "rotate" then calculates the altered positions of the rotated points. This also works for translation.

```
# Rotation
pcd.rotate(r, center = (0,0,0))

# Translation
pcd.translate(t)
```

With r = rotation matrix (3x3) and t = translation matrix (3x1).